# Invalid argument in foreach loop in php

Tags: php

So this below is the structure of JSON i have when I decode it in PHP, but for some reason I am having hard time to loop through this JSON object. I don't know how can I get each values of "incident","description","technique" from those array to save them In my DB.

```
array(1) {
      ["Access"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
          ["incident"]=>
          string(19) "sssssssssssssssssss"
          ["description"]=>
          string(10) "ssssssssss"
          ["technique"]=>
          string(19) "Link "
        }
        [1]=>
        array(3) {
          ["incident"]=>
          string(18) "ssssssssssssssssss"
          ["description"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["technique"]=>
          string(19) "Link "
        }
      }
    }
```

So far I have this PHP code but it's returning me an error saying invalid argument in first foreach loop.

```
$objectFirst =($_POST['Access1']);
$data = json_decode($objectFirst,true);

foreach ($data->Access as $tech){
    foreach($tech as $incident){
        foreach($incident as $ss){
            var_dump($ss->incident);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$data` is an array not an object. Try `$data['Access']` instead of `$data->Access`. And so on for other array elements inside your for loop.

Comment: ... or remove `true` from the second parameter of `json_decode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = [
    'access' =>
    [
        [
            'foo' => 'I',
            'bar' => 'got'
        ],
        [
            'foo' => 'a',
            'bar' => 'big'
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($data['access'] as $array)
    var_dump($array['foo'], $array['bar']);
```

Output:

```
string(1) "I"
string(3) "got"
string(1) "a"
string(3) "big"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you access the element with this notation, `$data->Access`, it means you try to access a property of the `$data` object. But in your case, `$data` is an array, therefore you have to use the array notation.

So it should be corrected as `$data['Access']`. One other issue in your code is the level of loops.

```
foreach ($data->Access as $tech){
    foreach($tech as $incident){
        foreach($incident as $ss){
            var_dump($ss->incident);
        }
    }
}
```

The inner most loop is incorrect because $incident will contain a string, not an array. When you try to access `$ss['incident']`, it will fail. So just change it to:

```
foreach ($data['Access'] as $tech){
    foreach($tech as $incident){
        var_dump($incident);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!